# How can I use sed to find a string and replace another string on a different line?

Tags: shell-script, find, replace

I have a file like this:

```
BEGIN
Name "TIPO_RECORD"
SqlType "12"
         Precision "255"
Name "Test"
         SqlType "12"
         Precision "255"
Name "xxxx"
         SqlType "12"
         Precision "255"
Name "Test"
         SqlType "12"
         Precision "255"
END
```

I need a script that finds the string "TEST", then replaced the first string "PRECISION" following it with "TRY".

Comment: Please show your expected output. Is it `Test` or `TEST`?

Comment: Apart from "TEST" not appearing in the example the sentence `Whenever it finds the string "TEST" must be replaced the first string "PRECISION" with "TRY"` is ungrammatical. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include your desired output. Remember that case (UPPER/lower) is important.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to replace the text as in you example, you can do:

```
sed '/Name "Test"/ {n;n;s/Precision/Try/;}'
```

To do it insensitive of case try:

```
sed '/Name "[Tt][Ee][Ss][Tt]"/ {n;n;s/[Pp][Rr][Ee][Cc][Ii][Ss][Ii][Oo][Nn]/Try/;}'
```

Or more simply with GNU `sed`:

```
sed '/Name "Test"/I {n;n;s/precision/Try/i;}'
```

Comment: With the first one, you'd need to enclose your actions in `{...}`. Note that GNU sed has the `I` flag for case insensitive matching (though relies on the locale, so for `i`, that could be `[Ii]` or `[Iı]` depending on the locale).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas The `i` flag of GNU `sed` works for `s///i`, but not for regexps used as addresses (it conflicts with the `i\ ` command, or something) .  The `{...}` is indeed needed, and some versions of BSD `sed` also needs a last `;` before the closing brace.

Comment: @lcd047, that's why I said `I`, not `i`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24994/discussion-on-answer-by-graeme-how-can-i-use-sed-to-find-a-string-and-replace-an).